# Data not updating from Event Bus

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get a data from another component (A) to component (B).

Component A:

```
methods: {
    setTemplate(template) {
        bus.$emit("setEmailTemplate", template);
    }
}
```

Here is where I want to fetch the data

Component B:

```
<template>
<div>
    <p>{{ template }}</p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { bus } from "../app";

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            template: ''
        };
    },
    created: function() {
        bus.$on("setEmailTemplate", (data) => {
            this.template = data;
        })
    }
};
</script>
```

However when I run the code, template returns empty string. It seems that template is not being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your event name is different while emitting and listening.

It has to be same for event bus to work.

Change your `methods` in Component A like so :

```
methods: {
    setTemplate(template) {
        bus.$emit("setEmailTemplate", template);
    }
}
```

---

AFTER EDIT

Without seeing more code, it would be hard to debug what problem you are facing.

I made a simple example of what you are trying. This might help you.

Working implementation attached.

[image: Edit EventBus example]

Comment: The event name is the same, sorry I might have overwritten the code while posting this. I've updated my question. Even if the event names are the same nothing is being shown still.

Comment: Do you get the `template` in the function where you are listerening?
Try console logging `data` before `this.template = data`.

Comment: Yes it's being logged properly. The only problem is updating the data in component B from the Event Bus

Comment: So the data you are emitting is a string or an object?

Comment: The data is a string

Comment: Check the codesandbox I attached then, I have used string in that implementation.

Comment: Thanks Utsav. I believe the reason why my code is not working is because Component A  and Component B is on a completely different routes.

Comment: Routes should not matter, if you have imported the same event bus instances in both the components.
Please upvote/accept my answer if it was any help to you.